# CPU and casting

Tags: c++, primitive-types

I am still a beginner in C++, and there are a few questions that I have been pondering upon lately. Basically I want to know what happens on an assembly level code and the CPU, when I cast a double to an integer. My question is not specific to int and doubles only, just trying to figure how the primitive data types interact with the CPU.

So if I am not wrong, an int is 4bytes and a double is 8 bytes. Say I have this code.

```
double x = 15.234;
int y = x;
```

To my knowledge, x will be casted into an int, and there will be some loss of data. Y will probably be equal to 15. But, what exactly happened in the CPU when it executed that piece of code? What happens to the 4 and 8 bytes of memory allocation for int and double respectively, how does it map the 8 bytes of information on to the 4 bytes?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Compile your program, and either look at the generated code, or debug the program and open the assembler view.  What happens is defined by the standard, how it happens is implementation specific.

Comment: [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/aFnfgs) is really good for these type of questions, but you will have to put a bit of effort into defeating compiler optimizations.